# alt-tab alternative different from VistaSwitcher for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, alt-tab

hi all i want to find an alternative to alt-tab different from VistaSwitcher. The reason behind this is that the standard alt-tab of windows 7 has a very anoying bug that isn't fixed yet and vistaSwitcher do not behave correctly when i'm debugging any application in Visual Studio, it just stop working till the moment i stop debugging. So anyone knows an alternative to alt-tab?

By the way the bug is discussed here : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/alt-tab-window-wont-stay-on-top-of-other-windows/9795ed00-3e9f-4751-8e6b-da9a25e820e0

Update(others bad alternative):

ALT-TAB Thingy:
i test this software but it don't have or at lest i don't find how that after tab release rise the selected window..i set the corresponding option but it slow not instantaneous one must specify a delay.

Comment: @Joey you are right i'm going to edit the "reported....

Comment: what happens if you try this: hold down Alt and keep it held down through the rest of these key presses, tap Alt Gr followed by the Tab key to scroll through the open windows.  Any improvement?  Not really an answer, just a quick and painless workaround (if it works).

Comment: @kez, thanks for the suggestion but the bug is unavoidable. When it appears the only thing that return the normal behaviour is kill the sidebar executable. But that is a real pain because i use the gadgets, so this also isn't a solution.

Comment: If you were more or less happy with VistaSwitcher but can't accept that it doesn't work when debugging, you might be satisfied with [AltTabAHK](https://github.com/studgeek/AltTabAHK) or one of its forks.  The functionality is similar and still works when debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this help (probably not) but have you tried the XP alt-tab which still wotks in 7?

hold alt

tap the other alt

press tab

I know it adds an extra keystroke but I don't even think about it any more

Comment: Oh, that's neat!